# how to use for-comprehension and skip running funcs if the previous func answered some condition?

Tags: scala

I created 3 duplications check in my mongo dao, to check 3 different cases of duplications in my db.
 (I know the best way to do this would be to create a compound index for those but unfortunately its not possible this moment and I need those checks)

so I thought do it this way, create this method:

```
  def checkPersonDuplication(person: Person): Future[(ValidationResult, Option[Person])] = for {
    sameSocIdIAndCountryVerification <- {
      logger.info("sameSocIdIAndCountryVerification is running")
      findPersonSameSocIdIAndCountry(person.socId, person.country)
    }
    sameNameAndCountryVerification <- {
      logger.info("sameNameAndCountryVerification is running")
      findPersonSameNameAndCountry(person.name, person.country)
    }
    sameLastNameAndCountryVerification <- {
      logger.info("sameLastNameAndCountryVerification is running")
      findPersonSameByNameAndCountry(person.lname, person.country)
    }
  } yield (sameSocIdIAndCountryVerification, sameNameAndCountryVerification, sameLastNameAndCountryVerification) match {
    case a if a._1.isDefined => (SameSocialSecurityNumberAndCountry, sameSocIdIAndCountryVerification)
    case b if b._2.isDefined => (SameNameAndCountry, sameNameAndCountryVerification)
    case c if c._3.isDefined => (SameLastNameAndCountry, sameLastNameAndCountryVerification)
    case _ => (ValidationSuccess, None)
  }
```

and now in the creation method I can do this:

```
 checkPersonDuplication(person) map {res => 
      res._1 match {
        case ValidationSuccess => // do something
        case SameSocialSecurityNumberAndCountry => throw DuplicateInsertion(s"???")
        case SameNameAndCountry => throw DuplicateInsertion(s"???")
        case SameLastNameAndCountry => throw DuplicateInsertion(s"???")
        }
  }
```

my problem is that if `sameSocIdIAndCountryVerification` is defined (since `findPersonSameSocIdIAndCountry` return Option[Person])  I dont want to run the other checks in the for-comprehension...

so I tried to add "if" after each, but it throws me `NoSuchElementException`. what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: It looks like `findPersonSameSocIdIAndCountry` returns a `Future` not an `Option`, otherwise the return type will be wrong.

Comment: yes its actually a ```Future[Option[Person]]```, I just tried to simplified the question :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version avoids unnecessary validations, but it is not particularly pretty:

```
def checkPersonDuplication(person: Person): Future[(ValidationResult, Option[Person])] = {
  logger.info("sameSocIdIAndCountryVerification is running")
  findPersonSameSocIdIAndCountry(person.socId, person.country).flatMap {
    case x@Some(_) =>
      Future.successful((SameSocialSecurityNumberAndCountry, x))
    case None =>
      logger.info("sameNameAndCountryVerification is running")
      findPersonSameNameAndCountry(person.name, person.country).flatMap {
        case x@Some(_) =>
          Future.successful((SameNameAndCountry, x))
        case None =>
          logger.info("sameLastNameAndCountryVerification is running")
          findPersonSameByNameAndCountry(person.lname, person.country).map {
            case x@Some(_) =>
              (SameLastNameAndCountry, x)
            case None =>
              (ValidationSuccess, None)
          }
      }
  }
}
```